# get index of DataTable column with name

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datarow

I have some code which sets the value of cells in a DataRow by column name i.e.

```
row["ColumnName"] = someValue;
```

I want to also set the value for this row in the column immediately to the right of the one found above.  Clearly if I was getting the cell by index rather than by column name this would be easy.  So is there a way of getting the column index from the column name thus allowing me to do:

```
row[index + 1] = someOtherValue;
```

i.e. do I need create some kind of dictionary of column index and column names when the table is initially created, or can I get the index from the column name later on without doing this?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can use [`DataColumn.Ordinal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.ordinal.aspx) to get the index of the column in the `DataTable`. So if you need the next column as mentioned use `Column.Ordinal + 1`:

```
row[row.Table.Columns["ColumnName"].Ordinal + 1] = someOtherValue;
```

### Warning:

This code returns the **next** column, so the one **after** `ColumnName`, as requested in the question.

Comment: You don't need the `+ 1` just `row[row.Table.Columns["ColumnName"].Ordinal] = someOtherValue;` will do.

Comment: @Piers: but  OP needed  the next column after another column.

Comment: You should write  `..to get the index of the NEXT column` then. I accidently used your line in my code while doing a mistake cuz of that +1. Thanks @PiersMyers for noticing it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, How to get all columns index in an array? example: `Table.Columns[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

Answer (score 42):

Try this:

```
int index = row.Table.Columns["ColumnName"].Ordinal;
```

Comment: +1 although as Tim beat you to it I'll mark his as the answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use [DataColumnCollection.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dd8zxxb(v=vs.110).aspx)

So that you can get the index of the required column by name then use it with your row:

```
row[dt.Columns.IndexOf("ColumnName")] = columnValue;
```

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an extension method of DataRow which gets me the object via the column name.

```
public static object Column(this DataRow source, string columnName)
{
    var c = source.Table.Columns[columnName];
    if (c != null)
    {
        return source.ItemArray[c.Ordinal];
    }

    throw new ObjectNotFoundException(string.Format("The column '{0}' was not found in this table", columnName));
}
```

And its called like this:

```
DataTable data = LoadDataTable();
foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
{        
    var obj = row.Column("YourColumnName");
    Console.WriteLine(obj);
}
```

Comment: Should this extension throw "ObjectNotFoundException" instead of "ItemNotFoundException"?? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objectnotfoundexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: -1 DataRow has that already built in your example if you did row["YourColumnName"] it will return the content of that cell. If the column doesn't exist it throws System.ArguementException and this is the message {"Column 'YourColumnName' does not belong to table Table."} So unless this has some performance gain please delete. Also this doesn't answer the question of how to get the index.