# Copy data from DataColumns from one DataTable to another

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have a DataTable with this structure:

DataTable1

```
NAME | SURNAME 
Joe  | Doe
John | Smith
```

and another table with this structure:

DataTable2

```
StudentName| StudentSurname | Status
Joe        | Doe            | OK
John       | Smith          | OK
```

I need to copy all the rows from DataTable1 to DataTable2, following this rule:

1. Data found in column NAME -> COPY ALL DATA TO  Column StudentName
2. Data found in column SURNAME-> COPY ALL DATA TO  Column StudentSurname
3. Always write OK in column Status.

What is the best way to achieve this?

EDIT: SO far I tried to do this:

```
foreach (DataColumn dc in DataTable1.Columns)
                {
                    if (DataTable1.Contains("NAME"))
                    {
                       //how can I copy it??
                    }
                }
```

I'm using C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the given example data, you can simple use the [DataTable.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) method to copy the entire datatable with structure and dataRows:

```
var copyDataTable = dataTable.Copy();
```

After that you can set the [DataColumn.DefaultValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.defaultvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) property for the third column. When adding new rows, this value is automatic being set:

```
copyDataTable.Columns["Status"].DefaultValue = "OK";
```

Answer (score 1):

you will probably want to base your foreach statement on rows instead of columns. You can iterate through the rows checking the value of that particular data row then update the value.

I think this code will do what you are looking to do.

```
DataTable NewTable = OldDataTable;

NewTable.Columns.Add("Status",typeOf(String));
```

(Adding column to DataTable: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfx3s9wd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
ForEach( DataRow row in NewTable)
{
//you can reference a column by it's name to assign and check values.
//It's used here to get the column number: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340264/get-index-of-datatable-column-with-name

     if (row["Name"] == "John")
     { 
         row["Status"] = true;
     }
 }
```

If you only want the last DataTable to have rows matching true. Use another foreach to go through the data table and remove the rows where row["Status"] != true.