# How to get index of column in table by name using WebElement selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, html-table

I tried to get the index of column (or row) table by name but I'm using selenium `WebElement` to capture interface of table or column, row,.... and I can't store captured table to `DataTable` (in System.Data.dll reference). I read in [get index of DataTable column with name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340264/get-index-of-datatable-column-with-name)  but I cannot store data in column of table to `DataColumn` and get it by using `DataColumn.Ordinal`. Here is my interface:

```
IWebElement Table = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='DivTable']//table"));
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> allRows = Table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
foreach(IWebElement row in allRows)
{
    ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> allCols = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
    foreach (IWebElement col in allCols)
    {
       //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the table html

Comment: How can I add? Can you demo for me, please

Comment: Click on 'edit' under your question and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it, and I would like to share it to everyone who is beginner like me :D

```
String sColValue = "Licensing";


//First loop will find the 'ClOCK TWER HOTEL' in the first column
for (int i=1;i<=allCols.Count;i++){
    string sValue = null;
    sValue = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='post-2924']/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/th["+i+"]")).Text;
    if(sValue.Equals(sColValue)){

        // If the sValue match with the description, it will initiate one more inner loop for all the columns of 'i' row 
        for (int j=1;j<=2;j++){
            string sRowValue= driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='post-2924']/div/table/tbody/tr["+j+"]/td["+i+"]")).Text;
            Console.WriteLine(sRowValue);
        }
    break;
}
}
```

You see, the index of column is "i" :D