# For loop took too much time if 20000+ users hit

Tags: c#, for-loop, optimization, query-optimization

Here I have 2 datatables, I want to make some changes runtime, so I used 2 for loops. But when user hit is huge like 20k+, system get down. It took more than 2 minutes every hit, I want to optimize, can anyone help on this?

```
Datatable BuybackResponse = ResourceCenterDAL.GetBuyBack(2);;
Datatable dt = ResourceCenterDAL.GetBuyBack(4);;
if (BuybackResponse.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < BuybackResponse.Count; k++)
        {
            var Exch = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Nsetradingsymbol"])) ? "NSE" : "BSE";

            //if (Exch == BuyBackExchangeMapping[Convert.ToInt32(BuybackResponse[k]["Exchange"])] &&
            if (BuybackResponse[k]["ProductCode"].Trim().ToLower() == Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Nsetradingsymbol"]).Trim().ToLower() ||
              BuybackResponse[k]["ProductCode"].Trim().ToLower() == Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Bsetradingsymbol"]).Trim().ToLower())
            {
                if (!Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["isBuyBack"]).Trim().ToLower().Equals("y"))
                    dt.Rows[i]["isBuyBack"] = "Y";
                dt.Rows[i]["productcode"] = BuybackResponse[k]["ProductCode"];
                BBcount++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["isBuyBack"])))
                    dt.Rows[i]["isBuyBack"] = "N";
            }
        }
        if (BBcount.Equals(BuybackResponse.Count)) { break; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure that it will significantly improve anything but you can move all the `dt.Rows[i]....` to variables outside the second loop.

Comment: If I use list instead of datatable and use linq, will it be helpful.....? @GuruStron

Comment: Trim().ToLower() should be done when the data is created in the arrays, not when you are looping them. That process drains your CPU like crazy.

Comment: however, if the problem is the database can't handle the load of the requests, perhaps you need to investigate your database? Did you create indexes? Did you add the values you are requesting to the columns in the index? 

Is your connection pool spent? 

how much data are you sending back and fourth? perhaps you are reaching the limit of your bandwith?

Comment: @MortenBork thank you, I'll do that

Comment: @MortenBork database indexes are created, database gives me a result in 1-2secs, issue in this loop only

Comment: You have expressions like this inside the doubly-nested loop: `BuybackResponse[k]["ProductCode"]`.  Outside one or both loops, figure out the ordinal value for the `["ProductCode"]` column and do the lookups by ordinal and not name.  It may speed things up a lot (given how many times it's executed)

Comment: Why not just do this all in the database and return the data already as you need it?

Comment: @Flydog57 ordinal means index..? do you want me to put [0], [1] instead of ["ProductCode"]...?

Comment: @zaggler both the source are different

Comment: They not use the same DB then or? `database indexes are created, database gives me a result in 1-2secs` is my assumption you could.

Comment: @zaggler let me check and confirm, 1st set of data I'm getting from database, 2nd I'm getting from API....

Comment: @zaggler: Look up what index is related to `"ProductCode"` before you start.  Then use that index instead of `"ProductCode"` when you want to access the ProductCode column.  No, don't count columns and just use `5`, that's very fragile.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340264/get-index-of-datatable-column-with-name. Up outside the outer loop do something like: `var productCodeIndex = dt.Columns["ProductCode"].Ordinal;` for each of the columns you are interested in.  Then, inside the loops, use something like `BuybackResponse[k][productCodeIndex]`

Comment: In this method: (ResourceCenterDAL.GetBuyBack(X))
Convert the data, as part of the "retrieval" of the data, that you change the value in: 

BuybackResponse[k]["ProductCode"] to a trim().ToLower()
and in 
dt.Rows[i]["Nsetradingsymbol"] to a trim().ToLower()

This way you wont do it on every loop. 

If then also add dataset as "cached" if that is permittable, you should see a large performance increase.